# How to change dialog box fonts (a tool created with ModelBuilder)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, python, arcmap, modelbuilder

I have created a model using ModelBuilder and now is the time to publish the model. But the problem is that I need to change the fonts of the dialog box. Does anybody knows how can I change these?

P.S. I have tried to change the Stylesheets, but nothing has changed.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The Description is a html content. You can set the style for the descriptions.

example:

```
<div style='font-family:JetBrains Mono;font-size=20;font-style: italic;'>Input GPS CSV file with X,Y fields and output the feature class.</div>
```

[image]

Comment: This only partly answers the question. Can you add how to change the font above the dialogue fields?

Comment: @Erik, sorry, I have no idea about the font in the dialogue fields yet.

Comment: Thanks, seems to be a nice solution, however it doesn't include the filed texts. But I couldn't find out how to set this code to the description. Would you help me with this please?
P.S. I have tried saving it to a notepad and load it in stylesheet (Model properties > General tab), but it changes the whole dialog box. 
@Erik

Comment: @Erik, you can set the description code in model properties.